# Confusions regarding apache server log?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, netbeans, java-io

> I am writing a program to print the contents of the 'apache server
>   log' on the console.But I find nothing on the \Apache Software
>   Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.34\logs. I am using apache with netbeans
>   and there is also nothing in apache tomcat 7.0.34 log window on
>   netbeans. How to configure that?  P.S- apache is successfully running
>   and I can connect to the port where it is running with other
>   computers and I am using win 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the **Tomcat** logs. Do not say Apache as most people will think you are referring to the Apache HTTP server.

The name of the log file is `catalina.out`. Maybe you should read [this](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Logging#Q10) entry and the following one on the FAQ